# TXT entry in DNS for both gmail and amazon ses

Tags: domain-name-system, spam, dns-zone, spam-filter, txt-record

It seems adding a TXT entry in DNS about Google is a good practice (when using gmail to send mail) to prevent being considered as Spammer. So I could add a TXT entry in my DNS records to:

```
example.org TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

But, this domain is also used to send mail via Amazon SES (I work for a web company that send mail via a web application). In other words, mails are sent from `myname@example.org` via Gmail and from `noreply@example.org` via Amazon SES. In order to avoid being considered as a spammer, should I:

- Do not add a TXT entry about SPS at all.
- Add a TXT entry for google "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
- Build something for both Amazon and Google (but I don't know what).
- Something else?

*Side note: MX entry for google (`aspmx.l.google.com`, etc.) and TXT for Amazon SES (`_amazonses._example.example.org TXT xxxyyyzzz`) are already set.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `~all` means that mail will come from the servers listed in the SPF record, but *may* also come other sources. However, by just specifying the Google record some mailers could be more wary of your emails that come from Amazon.

Your best bet would be to specify both. A quick search found the page listing SPF configuration for Amazon -
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html

So you'd end up with something like the following -

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all
```

You can also use `-all` if you are sure all your email comes from those 2 sources, although that can cause issues with badly configured forwarders.